# Advantages or alternatives to asynchronous events in my case of many subscribers

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, asynchronous

Let's imagine I have a class `Item`. The value of the item is taken from an external source. To have the least recent value, you must request the value as fast as possible in a loop.

Of course there is not only 1 `Item`, there are thousands. It's like:

```
while(active)
{
  foreach(Item item in items)
  {
    item.Value = RequestValue(item.Address);
  }
}
```

Every item can be used several times. To get changes, `Item` has a `ValueChanged` event where you can subscribe.

Let's imagine I have lots of subscribers, like 100 or 1000. Every handling costs time and can delay the loop behind the variables. The idea is: make the event asynchonous. In this case it doesn't matter how long the handler needs. However, in this question: ["Is it a recommended practice to raise all the events asynchronously"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017824/is-it-a-recommended-practice-to-raise-all-the-events-asynchronously-if) nobody recommented asynchronous events (except if there is a good performance reason).

I made a little performance test. I created a `SyncItem` and `AsyncItem` and a `Subscriber`. The `SyncItem` is calling `OnValueChanged` and `AsyncItem` is calling `new Thread(() => {OnValueChanged();}).Start();` if a value has changed.

I used a `Timer` to change values (to raise the events). I used a fast test (every 50ms) and a slow test (3s).

I used lots of `Subscriber` with the following handlers:

Handler 1

```
//Nothing
//Slow test: Sync is faster
//Fast test: Sync is faster, Async closing window does not exit application
```

Handler 2

```
Thread.Sleep(...);
//Slow test: Sync gets slower the higher the time is, at ~ 10ms equal to async
//Fast test: Times varying, Async closing window does not exit application
```

Handler 3

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { control.Text = value; } ));
//Slow test: Sync is faster (async needs longer than with Handler 1)
//Fast test: both UI does not react properly, Async UI also only rarely updated
```

Handler 4

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { control.Text = value; });
//Slow test: Async is faster, sync test: UI does not react properly
//Fast test: Sync UI does not react properly, Async OutOfMemoryException
```

I guess in the most cases, Handler 2 is used (any complex method that needs some time) and sometimes for UI Handler 3 or 4. Mainly because Handler 2, an async event handling seems to be the faster one.

However, I feel not comfortable to use asynchronous events. Beside the performance, is there any other good advantage? Or what would be alternatives to this? What are possible ways to handle with this situation?

Comment: `I don't know how good the performance is, I didn't tested it out.` Then you know exactly what you need to go do first.  When you've done that, *then* you can start considering the options.

Comment: @Servy I currently working on it. But it would be helpful to gain alternatives to compare the performance.

Comment: Personally i would use some sort of middleware like RabbitMQ to handle a publish/subscribe scenario like this.

Comment: @fedab Yet you don't even know if you need any alternatives.  If you find out that you actually have a problem, and you've looked at existing solutions *and tried them to see if they work*, and they don't, *then* it becomes appropriate to ask an SO question.  As it is you don't even know if you have a problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous event publication can help, but it can also raise new issues.  For example, what happens when the publisher fires events faster than the subscribers can consume them?  In effect you've just moved the problem from the publisher getting bogged down to the consumers getting bogged down with queued up notifications.  This can be particularly problematic if some of the consumers require the UI thread, which may mean further dispatching/queuing of events.  Worst case you can wind up in an effective deadlock state where the thread pool and/or message pump are so stuffed with messages that everything slows down to a crawl.

On a practical note for your particular application, consider whether it may make more sense to compile a list of 'changed items' and send a single event for the entire set after every update cycle.  Since you have thousands of items, presumably changing somewhat often, this may greatly reduce the number of event callbacks per cycle.

Comment: I'm not sure if `async`/`await` was available when this was written, but with TPL subscribers can now implement themselves as `async void` to allow the event publisher to not block while they process. Also, instead of creating a dedicated thread to raise the event on, it's likely much cheaper to use something like `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or more simply, `Task.Run(() => OnValueChanged())`

Comment: @mhand, Note that an `async void` event handler will still block the publisher up until the point that it performs an `await` that actually yields.  This typically means either using a `Task.Run`, a `Task.Delay` or calling some I/O method that internally yields pending an OS event.  It's important to realize that the `async` qualifier on a method doesn't mean 'runs asynchronously' but rather 'can resume asynchronously'.  It creates the capability for resumption, but it doesn't guarantee that it will ever yield.

Comment: That's completely correct. Another way to force the asynchronous continuation is through `await Task.Yield()` to yield immediately at the top of the event handler, forcing the rest of the event handler to run on a thread pool thread.